# ordering text by the agreement with keywords

Tags: python

I am trying to order a number of short paragraphs by their agreement with a list of keywords. This is used to provide a user with the text ordered by interest.

Let's assume I already have the list of keywords, hopefully reflecting the users interest. I thought this is a fairly standard procedure and expected some python package for that. But so far my Google search was not very successful.

I can easily come up with a brute force solution myself, but I was wondering whether somebody knows an efficient way to do this?

EDIT:
Ok here is an example:
    keywords = ['cats', 'food', 'Miau']

```
text1 = 'This is text about dogs'
text2 = 'This is text about food'
text3 = 'This is text about cat food'
```

I need a procedure which leads to the order text3, text2, text1
thanks

Comment: What does "agreement" mean here? Can you post an example?

Comment: ordering by how many of the (lets say) 100 keywords are found in the text

Comment: Could you provide example inputs and expected output? I'm afraid your question isn't very clear to me. Also, "please point me to a library" and "please write code for me" type questions are both disallowed by site policy, so you want to avoid sounding like either. Please [edit] the question to update it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest thing I can think of:

```
import string

input = open('document.txt', 'r')
text = input.read()

table = string.maketrans("","")
text = text.translate(table, string.punctuation)

wordlist = text.split()
agreement_cnt = 0

for word in list_of_keywords:
    agreement_cnt += wordlist.count(word)
```

got the removing punctuation bit from here: [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python).

Comment: While we await OP's edit: isn't this the brute force approach?

Comment: oops I didn't read the original question that closely apparently haha. I wonder what wouldn't be considered "the brute force approach" then. I don't think there is a way around checking each word versus each keyword. I think I might be missing the point of his request.

Comment: yep that solution will certainly work... do we all agree that this is also optimal?

Comment: just realized punctuation would break my first crack at it.  See the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be a good starting point:

```
>>> keywords = ['cats', 'food', 'Miau']
>>> text1 = 'This is a text about food fed to cats'
>>> matched_word_count = len(set(text1.split()).intersection(set(keywords)))
>>> print matched_word_count
2
```

If you want to correct for capitalization or capture word forms (i.e. 'cat' instead of 'cats'), there's obviously more to consider, though.

Taking the above and capturing match counts for a list of different strings, and then sorting the results to find the "best" match, should be relatively simple.